# cut a string after a specified pattern (comma)

Tags: shell, unix, cut

I want to cut a string and assign it to a variable after first occurrence of comma.

```
my_string="a,b,c,d,e,f"
```

Output expected:

```
output="b,c,d,e,f"
```

When I use the command

```
output=`echo $my_string | cut -d ',' f2
```

I am getting only `b` as output.

Comment: [Quote your variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells) -- `echo "$my_string" | ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a dash '-' to the end of your -f2 will output the remainder of the string.

```
$ echo "a,b,c,d,e,f,g"|cut -d, -f2-

b,c,d,e,f,g
```

Comment: This is because `-f` can take *ranges* of fields, and if you don't give the end of the range, the range will continue until the last field.

Answer (score 1):

With parameter expansion instead of `cut`:

```
$ my_string="a,b,c,d,e,f"
$ output="${my_string#*,}"
$ echo "$output"
b,c,d,e,f
```

`${my_string#*,}` stands for "remove everything up to and including the first comma from `my_string`" (see the [Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)).

Answer (score 0):

You must add the minus sign (-) after the position you are looking for.

```
a=`echo $my_string|cut -d "," -f 2-`
```

> echo $a
>   b,c,d,e,f